# ASPxGridView default unbound column filter from dropdown

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, devexpress

So I am using **ASPxGridView** for displaying data. I have an **unbound column** with **text** in there. Normally, you can filter the column:

-by selecting a value from dropdown

-by typing some text in filter input

The behaviour I'm trying to achieve is: When you select a special value from the dropdown, I want to filter the column with BeginsWith filter. I tried using

`<Settings AutoFilterCondition="BeginsWith" />`

but it only seems to work with input filtering: when I type text into filter input, column is filtered with specified filter, but when I chose value from dropdown, EqualsTo filter is used instead. How can I achieve my goal behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thankfully I've found a solution. What I did:

-get the FilterValue of interest

-and then

```
filtervalue.Query = "StartsWith([Column], 'value')"
```